# Windows Script Host & Quick Fix Engineering

Tags: wsh, hotfix

I want to get list of installed windows hotfix and updates. I use script below:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colQuickFixes = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering")

Set objDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

For Each objQuickFix in colQuickFixes
Wscript.Echo "Computer: " & objQuickFix.CSName
Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objQuickFix.Description
Wscript.Echo "Hot Fix ID: " & objQuickFix.HotFixID
If Not (IsNull(objQuickFix.InstallDate) Or _
IsEmpty(objQuickFix.InstallDate)) Then
objDateTime.Value = objQuickFix.InstallDate
Wscript.Echo "Installation Date: " & objDateTime.GetFileTime
Else
WScript.Echo "Install Date Type: " &
TypeName(objQuickFix.InstallDate)
End If
Wscript.Echo "Installed By: " & objQuickFix.InstalledBy
Next
```

When I run this script I get Error message:

```
Syntax error
Error Code 800A03EA
```

What's wrong in this piece of code? Thanks!
Sorry if my English is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line continuation character (`_`) here:

```
''#                        -----------
''#                                  |
''#                                  \/

WScript.Echo "Install Date Type: " & _
TypeName(objQuickFix.InstallDate)
```

Either add it or put the code in a singe line:

```
WScript.Echo "Install Date Type: " & TypeName(objQuickFix.InstallDate)
```